# Visualising complex solutions of quadratic polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I have the equation so that $x^2+x+2=0$. Since $\Delta<0$ we have two complex conjugate solutions. I am trying to visualise them on the Argand-Gauss plane to understand the algebra.

I have three axes such as:

- The $X$-axis for the real numbers (**input**)
- The $Y$-axis for the pure imaginary numbers (**input**)
- The $Z$-axis for the real numbers (**output**)

Therefore, the input is a complex number $x_c=(x+yi)$.

With the equation $x^2+x+2=0$, I will write a complex function so that:

$$
z={x_c}^2+x_c+2\\
z={(x+yi)}^2+(x+yi)+2\\
z=x^2+2xyi-y^2+x+yi+2\\
z=\color{green}{(x^2-y^2+x+2)}+\color{red}{(2xy+y)i}
$$

I have the real function $\color{green}{f(x,y)}$ in green and the pure imaginary function $\color{red}{g(x,y)}$ in red. I decided to plot these two functions in GeoGebra 3D:

> Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the output of $\color{red}{g(x,y)}$ has no *tangible* value. **It outputs pure imaginary numbers that cannot be shown**.

[image]

The 2D parabola is shown here:

[image]

Naturally, the complex solutions are the intercepts of the real and imaginary part:

[image]

This is the parabola known as the *"phantom graph"*, its maximum is the minimum of the real parabola and the intercepts on the Argand-Gauss plane are the solutions:

[image]

I would like to determine the expression of the *"phantom graph"*, or at least, demonstrate it. I have seen this [GeoGebra activity](https://www.geogebra.org/m/U2HRUfDr) where the *"phantom graph"* is determined with the expression:

$$
z=-a{x_c}^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}
$$

${x_c} = (x+yi)$ with the **real** part fixed to a certain offset (here $-\frac{1}{2}$).

Contrary to the real parabola which is:

$$
z=ax^2+2x+c
$$

> I would like to demonstrate the expression $z=-ay^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$ and understand **why this *"phantom graph"* turned upside down and rotated 90 degrees along the $Z$-axis yields the solutions when it intercepts the Argand-Gauss plane**.

Comment: Examples visualisation in [Wolfram](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11.1567243115.png) and in [Geogebra](https://help.geogebra.org/topic/how-repeat-visualization-in-geogebra).

Comment: @DmitryEzhov what does the yellow curve represent ?

Comment: curve `Re[F] == 0`.

Comment: And the red and green one ?

Comment: Red curve is `Im[F] - Re[F] == 0` and green is `Im[F] + Re[F] == 0`.